# css: What to change to make the size bigger?

Tags: css

I am not good with CSS, def a noob so this is over my head.

This is the address:
http://collinwedsdiana.info/friday13/?page_id=50

if you go there you will see there is a floating blockquote on the right that has this text:
"Nothing was going to hold her back from moving."

and I know/think the file responsible for that is:
http://collinwedsdiana.info/friday13/wp-content/themes/hitched/media/css/common.css

(there is a "?ver=3.6" at the end of the URL, but I have no idea why)

but I cannot seem to find a way to increase the text size.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inline css.

Best practice is to select from a single file (in your case common.css)

Add this line to the file:
This is the selector that will select your text is:

```
.entry blockquote p {font-size:YOUR_SIZE;}
```

Comment: Gahh! 2 hours of hunting around and one line is the solution!!! Where do I add that, in the CSS page or the wordpress page?

Comment: You should add it to common.css

Comment: I pasted: .entry blockquote p {font-size:38;} are you sure its .entrySPACEblockquoteSPACEp and there are no dots anywhere in between...

Comment: Space is correct. you have to specify a unit in your size so 38PX should work

Answer (score 1):

I appears that file below is also being applied to that page.

http://collinwedsdiana.info/friday13/wp-content/themes/hitched/media/css/charcoal_peach.css?ver=3.6

On line 422 of the file there is the css below (which is one place you can put the font size change). I have made it to 30px.

```
.post.panel .entry blockquote * {
    color: #929397 !important;
    font-size: 30px; /* <- new css  */
}
```

Or if you wanted to ensure that it only occurred on that one element you could create a new class to do the same; the new class below is called'text-large'.

```
<blockquote class="float_right">
    <p class="text-large">Nothing was going to hold her back from moving</p>
</blockquote>
```

and put the following somewhere in the css files

```
.text-large{
    font-size:30px;
}
```

if that still doesn't work you can use !important to force the declaration to take priority like this:

```
font-size:30px !important;
```

hope it helps

Comment: Also got it to work with the answer above, but upvoted you as your answer was helpful. Thansk!